# Exchange 2010 cross training - Common / Important tasks for deputy admins

Tags: exchange-2010

I have just finished an upgrade from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010. My final step is to cross-train those on my team who would be responsible for Exchange when I am absent. What are some (5 to 10 items) of the top items that anyone who touches Exchange 2010 should know?

Comment: Not an Exchange guy, but +1 for having the foresight to train people to fill in for you.  In addition to the training you should compile an operations runbook for your Exchange environment, that way if your fill-ins forget what you taught them they know where to look :-)

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Mail flow troubleshooting
2. Maibox creation/management
3. changes with 2003 vs 2010, for those hwo are already familiar with the pre-upgrade state of things
4. Backups - config, how to test they worked and how often to test, how to restore form backups
5. DR - what is implemented, and how it should be used
6. Company wide policies - for example: if a user can't send an attachment, an admin will know what sizes are restricted and wil adise the user directly, instead of searching the configs to find out it's not an error the user just ran into

Answer (score 2):

1) How to safely start up and shut down exchange services

2) What important files are to exchange (Hey the hard drive's full, I'm just gonna delete all those log files...)

3) How to deal with queries about stuff caught in your spam filters, even if that's not handled by exchange itself